# C++ Move constructor vs Copy constructor if no RAW pointer variable is present

Tags: c++

Learning C++ and all about constructors (Copy, Move), I am wondering what the correct/smart/efficient way would be.
The following scenario:
I have a class Movie that contains title, rating and counter. Every time I instantiate an object of that class, I want that object be placed into an array (called Movies) of objects. So if I watched 3 movies, my array would contains three instances of the class Movie. Since my movie class does not contain a RAW pointer, I am wondering if there is a difference in performance whether I use copy or move to add a particular movie into my collection. I hope my idea is clear to better understand the following code. Hopefully, someone can enlighten me. Thank you,

Mingw-w64 version 8.1.0, Win10, VSCode:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::string;
using std::vector;

class Movie
{
    private:
    string movieName;
    int movieRating;
    int movieCounter;

    public:
    string getName();
    Movie(string movieNameVal="None", int movieRatingVal=0);
    Movie(const Movie &source);
    Movie(Movie &&source);
    ~Movie();
};

Movie::Movie(string movieNameVal, int movieRatingVal)
: movieName(movieNameVal), movieRating(movieRatingVal) // Equivalent to movieName = movieNameVal; movieRating = movieRatingVal;
{
    cout << "Constructor called" << endl;
}

// Copy constructor
Movie::Movie(const Movie &source)
: Movie(source.movieName, source.movieRating)
{
    cout << "Copy constructor called" << endl;
}

// Move constructor
Movie::Movie(Movie &&source)
: movieName(source.movieName), movieRating(source.movieRating)
{
    cout << "Move constructor called" << endl;
}

Movie::~Movie()
{
    cout << "Destructor called" << endl;
}

int main()
{

    {
        vector<Movie> Movies1;
        cout << "------------Movies1: Copy constructor version------------" << endl;
        Movie movie1("Terminator 1", 5);
        Movies1.push_back(movie1);
    }

    cout << endl;
    cout << endl;
    cout << endl;
    {
        vector<Movie> Movies2;
        string namex = "Terminator 2";
        int ratingx = 5;
        cout << "------------Movies2: Move constructor version------------" << endl;
        Movies2.push_back(Movie(namex, ratingx));
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Looks like you're in that perfect world of having nothing but Rule of Five compliant members. This means you can observe the [Rule of Zero](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three) and do absolutely nothing!

Comment: Side note: Don't get hung up on pointers. Three/Five/Zero applies to any resources your object may have to manually manage. For example, you could have a network connection that MUST have proper handshaking on object destruction or a robot arm that MUST be returned to the correct positioning on shut-down.

Comment: On your question, the `string` can get you. There are performance advantages if the compiler can take advantage of moving the `string`. The compiler is smart. Maybe it can figure all of this out for you. Maybe not.

Comment: @user4581301 I don't think depends on the smartness of the particular compiler since the standard describes pretty well what an implicitly-defined move constructor must do, however, if the string implementation has the small string optimization, the move operation is a little more burdensome than you would expect, but yeah.

Comment: @MatG the observable behaviour is well-defined, but [the As-If Rule](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/as_if) allows the compiler to do anything it wants so long as the observable behaviour is unchanged. I'm routinely surprised by the crafty smurf the compiler did to my code.

Comment: Due to small string optimisations moving your class probably won't be any faster than copying. The easiest way to find out is to try it and benchmark

Answer (score 2):

You asking about the difference in performance when you append in a vector by copying or moving the object instance of your particular class.
First, you can always measure! I think the majority of time taken would go in the vector reallocating its `capacity()`, so when you have an idea of the number of objects that will be inserted, is always recommended to `reserve()` some memory.

Looking the output of your very code snippet:

```
------------Movies1: Copy constructor version------------
Constructor called
Constructor called
Copy constructor called
Destructor called
Destructor called

------------Movies2: Move constructor version------------
Constructor called
Move constructor called
Destructor called
Destructor called
```

I think I already see a winner. As said in the comments, in your particular class you may let the compiler generate the default constructors; generally the move may be more efficient than the copy (see more [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/move_constructor)).
However, consider this third possibility:

```
Movies3.emplace_back(namex, ratingx);
```

```
------------Movies3: emplace_back version------------
Constructor called
Destructor called
```

That wouldn't be so bad.